# Using "thread" in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient

I read somewhere that using `Thread.Abort()` method is one of the worst way to kill a thread because it does not free the memory assigned to this thread. (I don't know if that's true, correct me if it's wrong and `Abort()` method is the one I should use.) Therefore the best way to call killing a thread would be creating a variable that defiles if thread can run, ie:

```
bool threadResult;
t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => doSomeStuff());
t.Start();
abortThread();
//***************************************************
bool threadCanRun = true;
void doSomeStuff()
{
   while(threadCanRun)
      // do work
}
void abortThread()
{
   threadCanRun = false;
}
```

But... what if the thread cannot be stopped like that? Ie:

```
void doSomeStuff()
{
   WebClient wc = new Webclient();
   string url = "www.mywebsite.com";
   string content = wc.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Let's say that I want to spend less than 100ms on doing this thread^. If it won't end until the time passes (I'm using the following construction: `if (t.Join(100))` ) I should abort it somehow to keep my program running. So, what's the proper way to end up the working thread?

Sure, in this particular case I can use try-catch to handle most of exceptions, but this is just an example. Also, if my connection is really slow and the webpage is really big it would take more that 100ms and no exception will be thrown.

PS. I'm almost sure that it does not matter, but I'm working on WPF app with some Forms references. The target FW is NET 4.0.

Comment: You can use threads if you wish, but you may want to look into the benefits of a C# `Task`.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `Download...Async` and `CancelAsync` methods, and read up on `CancellationToken(Source)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your thread to be able to end in 100ms, you should design thread to check for running condition (`threadCanRun`) at least once per 100ms. Your question is too general so I cannot give you more precise answer.

Also, it is good programming practice to join with your thread immediately after `threadCanRun = false;` although somebody could disagree with that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using the ***BackgroundWorker*** class is safer but if you want to use a ***Thread*** then you have to implement a flag cancellation pattern.
If you are using .Net Framework 4.0 the you can use the ***CancellationTokenSource*** class like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    int threadCounter = 0;
    int mainCounter = 0;

    public void doSomeStuff(CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            threadCounter = i;
            // If you want to cancel the thread just call the Cancel method of the cancelSource.
            if (i == 88)
            {
                cancelSource.Cancel();
            } 

            if (cancelSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Do some Thread clean up here
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        new Thread(() => doSomeStuff(cancelSource.Token)).Start();

        // Do something else while the thread has not been cancelled
        while (!cancelSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            mainCounter++;
        }

        textBox1.Text = "The thread was cancelled when 'mainCounter' was at: " + mainCounter.ToString();            
    }
}
```

Also you can use the ***CancellationToken*** which has the ***IsCancellationRequested*** property and ***ThrowIfCancellationRequested*** method.

Comment: This does not answer the question.